# Libreoffice --headless refuses to convert unless root, won't work from PHP script

Tags: php, linux, libreoffice

Running headless Ubuntu server 12.something.

root@server: `chown www-data /my/path/ -R`

root@server: `chgrp www-data /my/path/ -R`

root@server: `chmod 755 /my/path/ -R`

root@server: `libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export /my/path/foo.ppt --outdir /my/path`

```
convert /my/path/foo.ppt -> /my/path/foo.pdf
```

Works like a charm.

---

root@server: `sudo -i -u www-data`

$`libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export /my/path/foo.ppt --outdir /my/path`

```
convert /my/path/foo.ppt -> /my/path/foo.pdf
Error: Please reverify input parameters...
```

Damn.

---

root@server: `sudo -i -u someotheruser`

$`libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export /my/path/foo.ppt --outdir /my/path`

```
convert /my/path/foo.ppt -> /my/path/foo.pdf
Error: Please reverify input parameters...
```

Damn.

Anyone have any idea? Trying to research this just confused me more. Is this probably a bug or some dependency quirk?

Comment: I have the same problem in Ubuntu 12.04, I am trying to convert ods files to pdf and it's working with sudo only

Comment: @Jacek Wysocki - I found a workaround using DocumentConverter.py with LibreOffice ( http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter ). Only trouble is, you need to daemonize libreoffice, which is kind of a pain in the ass and caused me some trouble. Oh, and the daemon still needs to run as root.

Comment: I have one too: `$ sudo visudo`
and I've added this line:
`%users ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: libreoffice`
after that `sudo libreoffice ...` without password

Answer (score 24):

I finally found an answer to this...
Add:

```
export HOME=/tmp &&
```

to the beginning, so:

```
export HOME=/tmp && libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export /my/path/foo.ppt --outdir /my/path
```

That worked for me on CentOS 6.5, and as shell_exec() in PHP.

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer. You saved my day.

Comment: You can also use: `HOME=/tmp libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export /my/path/foo.ppt --outdir /my/path` since you're only setting the HOME variable for one process.

Comment: Works well for me Thanks @greatmatter

Answer (score 5):

We faced the same issue when running the `soffice` binary headless (LibreOffice 5.0.5.2) in a CloudFoundry (Diego) container as part of a NodeJS app.

It seems newer versions of `libreoffice` do not expect a writeable `HOME`, but try to write to `TMPDIR`.

`strace` showed:

`8349 mkdir("app/tmp", 0777) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
8349 open("app/tmp/lu8349pzgegi.tmp", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

with `TMPDIR=app/tmp`

We fixed it by setting `TMPDIR` to a directory that is writeable by the App process' user, i.e. `TMPDIR=/tmp` on CloudFoundry:

`process.env.TMPDIR = "/tmp";`

Answer (score 5):

All what you need to do - create folder "/var/www/.config". When you try to convert some file under www-data user libreoffice require ".config" dir in user's home directory. But libreoffice has no permissions to create such folder. User www-data default home directory is "/var/www". So just run commands:

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/.config
sudo chmod 700 /var/www/.config
sudo chown www-data /var/www/.config
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the best solution. It worked for me as the www-data user under Ubuntu 18.04 and LibreOffice 6.3.1.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error, but the problem wasn't root access. The command was wrong.

This worked for me, getting text from a doc in LibreOffice 4.2.:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to txt:Text file_to_convert.odt
```

(http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/14130/how-do-i-install-filters-for-the-soffice-command/)

Comment: In addition I had to quote the filter name `soffice --headless --convert-to txt:"Text" ./*.docx` (yes this is for a LibreOffice install on Kubuntu 14.10, `apt-file` confirms that `libreoffice-common: /usr/bin/soffice`).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get over this issue by deleting the file first and then running the convert file. Looks like the overwrite of the file failed due to file owner issues.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was due to unwritable output folder. Use `--outdir` and specify a writeable folder.

If output file already exists, it will overwrite automatically.

Example:

```
$ libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir myfolder/ myfile.docx
```

Answer (score 0):

The environment variables used by LibreOffice are listed here: https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Environment_variables#System_Variables

The environment variable in question seems to be related to `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` (see https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#variables) but setting it does not solve the issue.

So the best that we can do is in the line of the answer from [greatmatter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27995679/1617295)

```
HOME=/tmp libreoffice ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Much as Jacek stated in his comment, make the user you are trying to execute the command as a sudoer with no password required.  Then change your libreoffice command to be

```
sudo libreoffice <rest of command>
```

Worked for me.  I had the same issue.

Answer (score -3):

You can not run libreoffice soffice binary with www-data user. Use a user with sudo privilege instead. Check my Gist https://gist.github.com/nathanielvarona/423bda9e4a8a4f0f9bbf#file-soffice-listener-sh

And since you are going to use this in PHP. Just give a try also to PHP-FPM. Install it and then modify the /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf file.

From

```
user = www-data 
group = www-data
```

To:

```
user = ubuntu
group = ubuntu
```

I've successfully run this in AWS EC2 and also with my VBox VMs.