# Running oowriter headless command using php exec() not executing

Tags: php, command-line-interface, openoffice-writer

I'm having issues using oowriter to convert a doc to a pdf using php `exec()`. The line i'm running below works fine in CLI, just not in php using exec().

```
$stdin = "/usr/bin/oowriter --headless --convert-to pdf -outdir /var/data/uploads/ /var/data/uploads/lorem.docx";

exec($stdin,$stdout,$return_int);
```

`$stdout` returns an empty `Array` and `$return_int` returns `0`.

I've searched around and the only possible solution I could find was adding the path to oowriter (which you can see i have done). Is there a permissions issue running this command as the apache user? There are a few posts on exec() not working in general, but I can successfully run commands for imagemagick using this method. Therefore it seems to me that this an application specific configuration issue with openoffice.

Appears to be a duplicate of the following, but no answers have been posted:

[unable to run oowriter as web user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169042/unable-to-run-oowriter-as-web-user)

FYI I'm using CentOS V6.1 and PHP v5.3.3. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a permission issue. Who is running `exec()` and under what permissions?

Comment: @budwiser I haven't specified any user so I can only assume the apache user is running exec() with any default permissions

Comment: Try to `chmod 777 /var/data/uploads/ -R` (for debugging purposes) just for once to see if we are dealing with user rights.

Comment: @budwiser `/var/data/uploads` is already set to 777 and FYI I can successfully execute imagemagick commands to files within this directory using exec() and apache user

Comment: To test this out it is possible to sudo using apache to test the command - `sudo apache command`. Also - you can sudo in exec :
`exec('echo 'password' | sudo -S leemurphy comand');`
That should mean you can run the command as root (to test) - then you could try setting it up on a normal user (create a user called 'runoffice')